# Relation between *sigma algebra* and *sigma models*

Tags: terminology, history, stochastic-processes, sigma-models

Is there connection between [sigma models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_model) in physics and [sigma algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra) in the probability theory?

Background: I have never had to study the former, but I am somewhat familiar with the sigma-algebra in the context of point processes.

Comment: Perhaps this question is better for math SE?

Comment: @N.Steinle it depends on whether sigma-models have any meaning outside of physics... which means that it is a part of the question.. which probably means that it belongs here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no connection at all, apart from the name.

The "sigma" in "sigma models" comes from the name given to a field in a simplified model, introduced by Gell-Mann and Levy,  that describes how chiral symmetry breaking gives mass to the proton and neutron and at the same time makes the pion almost massless.  It then, by some accident of history, became attached as a name to *any* field theory in which one  integrates over the set of all maps from  spacetime to some  target manifold. Although the integration  involves assigning a  measure on the set of all such maps, there is probably no rigorous way to define a sigma algebra for  this measure.